# How to solve diagonally constraint sudoku?

Tags: python-3.x, sudoku

Write a program to solve a Sudoku puzzle by filling the empty cells where  `0` represent empty cell.

Rules:

- All the number in sudoku must appear exactly once in diagonal running from top-left to bottom-right.
- All the number in sudoku must appear exactly
  once in diagonal running from top-right to bottom-left.
- All the number in sudoku
  must appear exactly once in a 3*3 sub-grid.

However number can repeat in row or column.

Constraints:
N = 9; where N represent rows and column of grid.

What I have tried:

```
N = 9
def printing(arr):
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            print(arr[i][j], end=" ")
        print()


def isSafe(grid, row, col, num):
    for x in range(9):
        if grid[x][x] == num:
            return False
    cl = 0
    for y in range(8, -1, -1):
        if grid[cl][y] == num:
            cl += 1
            return False
    startRow = row - row % 3
    startCol = col - col % 3
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if grid[i + startRow][j + startCol] == num:
                return False
    return True


def solveSudoku(grid, row, col):
    if (row == N - 1 and col == N):
        return True
    if col == N:
        row += 1
        col = 0
    if grid[row][col] > 0:
        return solveSudoku(grid, row, col + 1)
    for num in range(1, N + 1, 1):
        if isSafe(grid, row, col, num):
            grid[row][col] = num
            print(grid)
            if solveSudoku(grid, row, col + 1):
                return True
        grid[row][col] = 0
    return False
if (solveSudoku(grid, 0, 0)):
    printing(grid)
else:
    print("Solution does not exist")
```

Input:

```
grid = 
[
    [0, 3, 7, 0, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0],
    [5, 0, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7],
    [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
    [2, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 5, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2, 0, 7],
    [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 7, 4, 2],
    [0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Output:

```
8 3 7 0 4 2 1 2 4
5 0 6 1 8 6 3 6 7 
4 1 2 7 3 5 5 0 8 
2 8 3 5 4 8 6 0 5 
6 5 0 0 7 1 2 1 7 
1 4 7 3 2 6 8 4 3 
7 8 1 4 1 6 3 5 0 
6 2 3 7 3 5 7 4 2 
0 5 4 2 8 0 6 8 1
```

Basically I am stuck on the implementation of checking distinct number along diagonal. So question is how I can make sure that no elements gets repeated in those diagonal and sub-grid.

Comment: there is something clearly wrong with your rule set or given numbers..  for example, box 2, which has no diagonal, has no constraint other then one set of the digits one through nine.   if there are repeats allowed, then how can a unique solution be found.  if subgrid is meant to indicate any 3x3 box, then the given numbers in the grid you provide break that rule as there are several 2s and 3s two squares away.

Comment: As for the fix to your diagonals, those checks need only to be done if row==col  for the first diagonal and if col == (8-row) for the other diagonal.

Comment: @toppk repetition are allowed in row or column of not in diagonal.

Comment: @toppk two sub-grid can have same number along row or column it must fulfill above three constraint.

Comment: Can subgrids overlap, or is it just 9 subgrids?

Comment: @toppk 9 subgrid each having 3 row and 3 column

Comment: @toppk I'm adding output it'll more clarity

Comment: look at row 2, column 5 and 6, which you provided in the output as 8 and 6.  is there a diagonal constraint on that cell?  no.  so how can you tell it is 8/6 and not 6/8?  like I said, you are using the diagonal constraint even if you are not on the diagonal.   the rules or given are broken.

Comment: @toppk are you using 0-based indexing

Comment: @toppk both 5 are in different sub-grid so it's fine

Comment: @toppk look again they both are in different sub-grid and they are following diagonal constraint.

Comment: r2c5 and r2c6 are in the same subgrid.  your visual indicates that there are multiple diagonals, so the rule that said each diagonal must contained every digit in the sodoku is not accurate.    since the diagonal that goes starts in r1c5 will only contain 5 digits.

Comment: @topkk r2c5 is 8 and r2c6 is 6 now if you see all diagonal element along 8 is 0>8>5>6>1>3 from top-left  to right-bottom and all diagonal element along 6 is 4>6>5>0>7 from top-left to right-bottom

Comment: @toppk and 8 and 6 are contained in second sub-grid and all element in second sub-grid are unique

Comment: @toppk now if you track down 8 and 6 along top-right to bottom-left you'll find all element along that diagonal are unique.